# ASP SQL query throws an error

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have an error in the following sql.

```
    (SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url
FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on
lsl.sid = lr.sid 
WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' 
ORDER BY larry_ranking DESC Limit 2)


UNION


(SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url
FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on
lsl.sid = lr.sid 
WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' AND shorthand='sexier')
```

I put it into one line:

```
    dim rsFav
sSQL = "(SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on lsl.sid = lr.sid WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' ORDER BY larry_ranking DESC Limit 2) UNION (SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on lsl.sid = lr.sid WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' AND shorthand='sexier')"
Set rsFav = objConn.Execute(sSQL)
```

I get this error..

> ```
> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1' Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
> ```
>
> /sandbox/inc_fav_sites.asp, line 29

I think the problem is in the sql string....not in the asp code..cause I didnt touch it

This line 29 `<a href="http://livecamdeals.com/review.asp?sitename=<%=LCase(rsFav(""))%>"></a>`

Sorry, I dont know asp programming but sql..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that, in ASP, you are asking the RecordSet (i.e. the results back from SQL) for a column called `""` (empty-string).

Obviously, you're SQL does not return such a column!!

The fix is to change the ASP code to select the correct column. E.g. to select the `site_url` column :

```
LCase(rsFav("site_url")
```

Comment: Thanks , Awesome, It has helped